# Disable word wrapping in the end

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I have a block with some text and image inside.

Like:

```
<div>I just posted a new photo from my iPhone <img></div>
```

Image in the end has dimensions of 16x16.

**The problem is**, text varies and **sometimes >just image< goes to a new line**. It **should always go with some word**, image must not travel alone.

**How do I do it?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a non-breaking space:

```
...from my iPhone&nbsp;<img>...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try `white-space: nowrap` in your CSS. This prevents line wraps in your paragraphs.